# How can I improve my progress bar match to follow image (color, angle, shape etc.)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have created a circular progress-bar, and have made it follow as closely as possible to the design in the image below.

But I'm having difficulty having it match the design in the picture below (color, angle, shape etc.):

I don't know how to match :

- the color of the above?
- or the shape?

Design I'm wanting to follow:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVzZm.png]

My current design looks like the below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzyiL.png]

My code so far is below:

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="75"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/style_circular_fill"
        android:secondaryProgress="10"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

**style_circular_fill.xml**

```
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="270" >
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
            android:useLevel="true" >
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#A9E2F3"
                android:endColor="#A9E2F3"
                android:startColor="#A9E2F3"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="270" >
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
            android:useLevel="true" >
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#26ce61"
                android:endColor="#26ce61"
                android:startColor="#26ce61"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [CircleProgress](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress) library. One of the examples they feature looks quite similar to that of your requirement.

I haven't used it, so cannot confirm the ease of its use.

For the sake of being balanced, check out [this list](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/76) of Progress Bar libraries. There may be a library that can achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest that u export the image to the match resources folders (mdpi,hdpi, and so on...);

after that create an animation xml file like this (let's call this file "progress_bar_animation.xml"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/your_resource_file_name"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="1800" />
```

and then create a progress bar style (in style.xml file)

```
 <style name="ProgressBar" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
        <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_bar_animation</item>
    </style>
```

and finally add a progress bar to your xml and set the style you create before, like this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/ProgressBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this progress dialogue

```
  public class MyCustomProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {

private Context c;
private ProgressWheel pd;
private ImageView imgLogo;

public MyCustomProgressDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    c=context;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.progress_bar_loading);

}

@Override
public void show() {
    super.show();
}

@Override
public void dismiss() {
    super.dismiss();
}
}
```

progress_bar_loading.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/transperent"
android:gravity="center"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_x"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text=" "
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<com.organigoal.customcontrol.ProgressWheel
    android:id="@+id/progress_wheel"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    wheel:barColor="@color/grey"
    wheel:progressIndeterminate="true"/>
```